# Wait for Object initiated to return list and then continue

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I have a master python script, that creates two objects

```
obj1 = xmlobj()
list1, list2, list3 = obj1.parsexml("xmlfile")
//parsexml returns me three lists
obj2 = htmlobj()
str1 = obj2.createhtmltable(list1, list2, list3)
//creates a html table
```

But, when I run script, master script does not wait for the obj1.parsexml to return value, and executes and immediately goes to next statement of creating obj2, thus not even executing createhtmltable as list1, list2, list3 has no return values in it. Separately, parsexml works fine without any error

How can I fix this, thank you

Comment: You need to use input and output Queues.  A group of threads should get filenames/urls from a *task* Queue, and dump the results of `parsexml` in a *results* Queue.  Then your main thread can read from the results Queue and convert to html files.

Comment: Sure, Will try that and update it

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense. After calling `obj1.parsexml("xmlfile")` execution doesn't continue before this call returns. If you start threads inside that function, those will run independently, but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import Queue  #python 3.x => import queue
import urllib2  #python 3.x => import urllib.request
import threading

urls = [
        "http://www.apple.com",
        "http://www.yahoo.com",
        "http://www.google.com",
        "http://www.espn.com",
]

def do_stuff():
    while True:
        url = task_q.get()

        if url == "NO_MORE_DATA":
            break

        data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()[:200]
        results_q.put(data)

#Create the Queues:
task_q = Queue.Queue()
results_q = Queue.Queue()

num_worker_threads = 2

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff)
    t.daemon = True  #daemon threads are killed when the main thread finishes
    t.start()  #All threads block because the task_q is empty.

#Add the tasks/urls to the task_q:
for url in urls:
    task_q.put(url)

#Like frantic dogs, all the threads are chomping on the task_q...

#Add a stop for each thread, so that after all the urls 
#have been removed from the task_q, the threads will terminate:
for i in range(num_worker_threads):   
    task_q.put("NO_MORE_DATA")  

results_count = len(urls)  #Need to know how many results are expected in order to know when to stop reading from the results_q

while True:
    result = results_q.get()

    #process the result here
    print result
    print '-' * 10

    results_count -= 1
    if results_count == 0:  #then all results have been processed, so you should stop trying to read from the results_q
        break
```

> Queue.join()
>   Blocks until all items in the queue have been gotten and
>   processed.
>
> The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to the
>   queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer thread calls
>   task_done() to indicate that the item was retrieved and all work on it
>   is complete. When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, join()
>   unblocks.
>   https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/queue.html#module-Queue

Yeah, but who wants to wait until *all* the results have been added to the results Queue before starting to process the results.  Why not start processing the first result as soon as it is available?